# Deserialize an array of struct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, deserialization

Once again I'm receiving structs via UDP from a C++ programm,
Now I ported the structs to C#, Example:

```
[Serializable]
struct sample
{
public int in;
public byte[] arr;
public int[] arr2;
public float fl;
}
```

Ok so how does the Deserializer know when one array ends and the other begins?
Can specify somehow how big the array is?
I don't want to use fixed, since this makes my code unsafe, and I also can't use a Constructor since structs are not allowed to contain constructors without parameters.

Any suggestions?

//edit:

the arrays are known to be 32 and 4 long.
the problem is that I don't know how to pass this information to the deserialiser

then sender is C++ an works like this:

```
char* pr = &sample;
int i=0;
while (i<sizeof(sample))
{
 udp.send(*(pr+i))
 i++;
}
```

Comment: ok switching the whole thing to classes helps with the constructor problem,
but I still don't geht HOW this works, can anybody explain?

Comment: How *what* works? What is serializing the C++ here? You haven't told us what you have currently in terms of your attempt at deserialization, so it is hard to comment on "HOW this works"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you have told us that the lengths are of pre-defined length, then the following statement becomes clearer:

> I don't know how to pass this information to the deserialiser

In fact, it becomes *moot*. There is no pre-defined serializer that is going to help you here. You have two options:

A: write your own serializer, and process the data now that you know the format - perhaps using `BinaryReader`:

```
using(var reader = new BinaryReader(source)) {

    int in = reader.ReadInt32();
    byte[] arr = reader.ReadBytes(32);
    int[] arr2 = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) arr2[i] = reader.ReadInt32();
    float fl = reader.ReadSingle();

    var obj = /* something involving ^^^ */
}
```

B: buffer 56 bytes, and use really nasty `unsafe` / `fixed` / pointer-banging code

I strongly suggest the first. In particular, this will also allow you to address endianness if required.

***IN THE NAME OF EVERYTHING SACRED TO YOU, DO NOT DO THIS:***

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
unsafe struct sample
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public int @in;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public fixed byte arr[32];
    [FieldOffset(36)] public fixed int arr2[4];
    [FieldOffset(52)] public float fl;    
}

static class Program
{
    unsafe static void Main()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[56];
        new Random().NextBytes(buffer); // some data...

        sample result;
        fixed(byte* tmp = buffer)
        {
            sample* ptr = (sample*) tmp;
            result = ptr[0];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.@in);
        Console.WriteLine(result.fl);
    }    
}
```

For larger buffers, you can treat `ptr` as an unsafe array of multiple `sample`, accessed by index:

```
int @in = ptr[i].@in;
```

(etc)

But honestly... there are so many things "evil" with that, I honestly don't know where to begin... just... unless you know **absolutely** what every line in there is doing, have done it before, and understand all the traps... **DON'T EVEN THINK ABOUT IT**

Comment: well i'm actually used to pointers, but I agree that it would be better to find a way around them.
I'm hate to write an custom deserialzer, but well that seems to be the right way.
Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format used to pass the structure over the wire.

If say it's json, then each field will have a key and the array will be surrounded by [].

If say it's xml, then you would expect an arr node with child nodes.

If it's some arbitrary format, you need to know the format.

Deserializers have some default behavior but if the passed data is not in default format, you need to tell them exactly how to deserialize.

Comment: The sender just puts a pointer to the start of the struct and sends byte after byte, i guess this is the same as arbitrary.
so _I_ know how long the array is, but how do I tell the serialiser?

Comment: @ChristianElsner and what do you mean by "a pointer" in this context? A pointer is meaningless once serialized...

Comment: Given your code, it is highly dependent on the implementation of your computer (the C++ one), how your array will be written to the wire. It will be dependent on how your computer stores arrays in memory. If you have control over that udp code, I'd suggest you change it to not use a byte dump, instead decide the format you want to write and then write it.

Comment: I cannot change the C++ code, I'm already very happy that I got read access to figure out how this stuff works...
On the behalf of being documented: Documented by Code

Comment: Well in that case, you can only hope to inspect the byte array, if it contains the 'length of the array' information. If it doesn't (and my guess is it will not), then you cannot do anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

And how is the raw data documented? I would expect there to be something to tell you here, for example, I might expect it to say the format is (purely an example)

- 4 bytes NBO Int32 (`in`)
- 4 bytes NBO Int32 (length of `arr`)
- len bytes (`arr`)
- 4 bytes NBO (length of `arr2`)
- 4 * len bytes (`arr2`, each in NBO Int32)
- 4 bytes IEEE-754 (`fl`)

You need to know the format.

Edit: if the C++ arrays are of a known fixed length, then you simply need to know those lengths in advance.